# Why is "Int -> Int" not the same as "Int x => x -> x"? In this case the second example is invalid, correct?

Tags: haskell

Why aren't these two type definitions equivalent?

Also, why isn't "Num a => a -> a" equivalent to "Num -> Num"? In this case the second example is invalid, correct?

I'm assuming it has to do with Num being a *Class* and Int being a *Type*, but I'm not clear on what the difference between a *Class* and *Type* is in Haskell and how the difference between them is relevant to what type definitions are allowed and what type definitions are not.

Is there a list of Classes and Types in Haskell somewhere?

Comment: "Is there a list of classes and types in Haskell somewhere?" The [Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1270006.3) has a diagram of the Prelude classes and types, and the [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) is a more complete introduction to popular typeclasses. Of course, nothing can be fully complete, as programmers can define new types and classes at will.

Comment: The full name for Haskell “class” is “*type* class”. Type classes are not the same as classes from OOP. A type class literally describes a “class of types”. You say which types belong to such a class of types by defining “instances” of the type class (also different meaning for the word “instance” from OOP).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, those are not equivalent. `Int x` is a kind error. `Int` has kind `Type`, and then you're trying to apply it to `x` which has also kind `Type`. This is like writing `'f' 'x'` on the value level – you're trying to apply the function `'f'` to the value `'x'` but both actually have type `Char`. Doesn't work.

By contrast, `Num x` is fine, because `Num` has kind `Type -> Constraint` – so this can be applied to something of kind `Type` just fine.

```
ghci> :k Int
Int :: Type
ghci> :k Num
Num :: Type -> Constraint
```

But the signature

```
   Num x => x -> x
```

is not the same as the signature

```
   Int -> Int
```

although many functions could be defined with either of those signatures. For example, the following both compile without problem:

```
quadruple :: Int -> Int
quadruple = (*4)

quadruple' :: Num x => x -> x
quadruple' = (*4)
```

The difference is that `quadruple` can only be applied to values of the exact type `Int`. For example, `quadruple 3.14` is a type error, because you're trying to feed a fractional value as the argument, which is incompatible with the expected `Int` input. Whereas `quadruple' 3.14` works just fine, by instantiating the `x` type-variable to (for example) `Double`. The result is then also of type `Double`. In other words, the function then specializes to

```
quadruple'' :: Double -> Double
quadruple'' = quadruple'
```